# What AWS product do I use for creating a streaming platform like Netflix or Prime Video?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-streaming

I'm currently making a website for movie streaming on demand and I'm stuck at the part of web hosting. I want to use AWS as it is in the cloud which makes it easy for me to upgrade in the future if needed.

So what do I use?

- S3
- EC2
- Cloudfront
- Lighsail

So yeah. I'm a little lost with all the options and I need your help as I cannot really understand it all. Except for the part that I definitely need AWS route 53.

Comment: A streaming platform isn't going to use any single product. You're going to need multiple products. You'll probably need S3, Cloudfront, EC2, Route53, Elemental MediaLive, Elemental MediaPackage and probably several other services depending on your needs.

Comment: This is a massive undertaking. If you are really working on something like this (and not just asking as a thought experiment) you should look into platforms that hide the dozens of different systems that need to be integrated. Services like mux.com, and its competitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Amazon S3 is ideal for storing the videos
- [AWS Elemental](https://www.elemental.com/) services can offer video-specific capabilities like converting, transporting and streaming video

You would want to use [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) to grant access to data once users have signed-into the service, or you might need a back-end that sends streaming packets to the browser.